# Get the same (x,y) when tapping the screen in different orientation using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, coordinates

Is there a way to get the same coordinates (x,y) when the user tap on the screen ?

I know in landscape the x coordinate will be the y coordinate in portrait and y will be x but in landscape orientation the user may scroll down so the coordinates will be different

Like in this picture what can I do to get the same coordinates of the circle ?
I am using the coordinates to get information from the database when the user tap on PDF page to get certain information

[image]

This is the code of this example :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:native_pdf_view/native_pdf_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  double posx = 100.0;
  double posy = 100.0;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.white),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Coordinates'),
          ),
          body: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: 200,
                      left: 70,
                      child: Container(
                        //color: Colors.red,
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      // color: Colors.green,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 700,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          )));
}
```

Comment: Would it be useful if you related the touch coordinate relative to the widget to the widget's width and height, and use the ratio? It would then be the same in both portrait and landscape orientations.

Comment: Thank you @hacker1024 for your comment. Can you please explain more?

Comment: And can you show me how to do this with the example in the question?